# Javascript, Bookmarklets, redirect and then make action

Tags: javascript, redirect, bookmarklet

I am trying to make a bookmarklet with two actions. First is `window.location = "http://example.com";`, and second is `alert("123");`.

Does it possible to do with bookmarklet?

Here is the logic of code:

```
javascript:(function{
window.location = "http://example.com";
var waitForText = setInterval(function(){
    bodytext = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerText;
    if(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerText.indexOf('Thank you for visiting example.com.') > -1){
        alert("123");
        clearInterval(waitForText);
    }
}, 1000);
})();
```

Comment: You cannot direct someone off of a site and then execute client code from the site they were just taken from, no...

Comment: The problem is that the script is effectively loaded into the current page and run. So when the page is redirected, the page disappears, and so does your script.